# Magento: How to get SQL query of Product load?

Tags: sql, magento

What is the full SQL query for product load?

I mean, how to get the full SQL query for this code:-

```
$productId = 52;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

I know, we can get the SQL query for collection object through printLogQuery. Example:-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->printLogQuery(true);
```

I couldn't find such for product load(). Any idea?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`load()` is actually the method which execute query on database. For that reason there is no option to "find such for product `load()`". Final query is generated before `load()` method.

Additionaly, easier method to get query on the screen for example is (on your example):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: need to terminate that last statement.

Comment: As @bluescrubbie is saying, you don't have to call `->__toString()` when you echo. If it is defined in the class, then it is automatically called when echoing. Similarly, you can do this: `$sql = (string)$collection->getSelect()`. The `(string)` also results in an automatic call to `__toString()`

Answer (score 6):

You can dump the actual query via

To enable SQL Debugging, 
Go to

```
lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

change line 98

```
protected $_debug = false;
```

to

```
protected $_debug = true;
```

It will write the SQL straight to the value of line 126

```
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can benefit from logging all queries for a page load.
Refer the following article for more info:
http://blogs.ifuelinteractive.com/2009/10/18/logging-all-sql-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

There's not just one query for the product load.

Take a look at the `load()` method from the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract` class to see how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Well $product doesn't have a ->getSelect() method but a collection does we can workaround that by doing

```
$product_sku = 'sku';
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $product_sku);
echo $products->getSelect();
```

Which will echo

> SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (e.sku = 'slickerBrush_config')

Answer (score 0):

To see what all queries get fired while calling ->load() method on any modal. Better check into mysql.log file. Check your mysql loggin is enabled or Add this in my.cnf and then restart MySQL server:

```
general_log = 1
log=/var/log/mysqld_query.log
```

Most of the time these two lines are commented out or not preset better check in other conf also like my.conf, mysql.conf etc. Also time to time empty this file or its size grows very fast might take away most of server memory.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the sql select from

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString()
```

is not reliable. Activate the db log, with n98-magerun.phar

```
n98-magerun.phar dev:log:db
```

then you can tail the log file

```
tail -f var/debug/pdo_mysql.log
```

to see realtime executing queries.
When you are done, deactivate the db log, using the same command

```
n98-magerun.phar dev:log:db
```